# Prove there is a formula $\phi(x,z)$ of VC dimension $\kappa$ and dual VC dimension $2^\kappa$

Tags: combinatorics, logic, model-theory, machine-learning, computational-geometry

I first recall some definition since the notation can differ somewhat.

Consider a formula $\phi(x,z)$ defining a binary relation $\{(u,v)\in U\times V|\quad \phi(u,v)\}$.
$\phi$ defines subsets of $U$ as $\phi(U,b)=\{a\in U|\quad \phi(a,b)\}$.
The corresponding collection of defined subsets is $\phi(U,b)_{b\in V}\subset\wp(U)$
Now, we say $\phi$ has VC dimension $\kappa$ if $\kappa$ is the maximum cardinality of $A\subset U$ such that $\phi$ shatters $A$ i.e. $\phi(A,b)_{b\in V}=\wp(A)$
The dual dimension is just the dimension of the dual formula $\phi^*(z,x):=\phi(x,z)$

Now I am asked to find a formula as in the title.

The only way I know to produce a formula (actually a set-system, in an equivalent fashion) of arbitrary $\kappa$ VC dimension is to consider: 
$$\Phi=U^{\leq\kappa}:=\{A\subset U|\quad |A|\leq\kappa\}\subset\wp(U)$$

Now this is equivalent to the binary relation defined by 
$$\phi(u,B)\Leftrightarrow u\in B \quad\quad on\ \ U\times\Phi$$

**So my try is to prove that $\phi^*(B,u)$ has VC dimension $2^k$.**
To asess that it has dimension $\geq2^\kappa$ I would try by proving that since there must be $A\subset U\ \ |A|=\kappa$ shattered by $\phi$ then $\phi^*$ shatters $\wp(A)\subset \phi\ \ |\wp(A)|=2^\kappa$.

Anyhow I am quite stuck on this.
I think that similarly one can prove that $\phi^*$ has VC dimension $\leq 2^\kappa$

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume $\kappa$ is finite in this answer. For infinite $\kappa$, there's one major issue: The function $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ may not be strictly increasing on infinite cardinals. If you're really interested in infinite $\kappa$, I think that everything I wrote goes through with minor modifications if you assume GCH. I'm not sure what happens when $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ is not strictly increasing.

---

The set system $\mathcal{P}_{\leq\kappa}(U) = \{A\subseteq U\mid |A|\leq \kappa\}$ is a natural guess, since it is somehow the canonical set system with VC dimension $\kappa$. Unfortunately, it can't have dual VC-dimension $2^\kappa$. Suppose we have $\mathcal{B} = \{B_1,\dots,B_{d}\}\in \wp_{\leq\kappa}(U)$. To shatter $\mathcal{B}$, we need a family $(a_X)_{X\subseteq \mathcal{B}}$  of $2^{d}$-many (distinct) elements of $U$ such that for any subset $X\subseteq \mathcal{B}$, we have $a_X\in B_j$ if and only if $B_j\in X$. But for each $j$, $B_j$ is in exactly half of the $2^{d}$-many subsets of $\mathcal{B}$, so $B_j$ contains $2^{d-1}$ many distinct elements $a_X$, and hence $\kappa \geq |B_j|\geq 2^{d-1}$. This shows that $\lfloor \log_2(\kappa)\rfloor + 1$ is an upper bound for the dual VC dimension of $\mathcal{P}_{\leq\kappa}(U)$. And that quantity is much smaller than $2^\kappa$, for all $\kappa>0$.

However, this suggests that $\mathcal{P}_{\leq 2^\kappa}(U)$ might be an example of a set system with VC dimension $2^\kappa$ and dual VC dimension $\kappa$. This is equivalent to what you asked for, by dualizing. In fact, this system has dual VC dimension $\kappa+1$. But we can fix the example:  rather than considering the subsets of size at most $2^\kappa$ of some large set $U$, let's just think about the full power set of a set $U$ of size $2^\kappa$ (and note that all such sets have size at most $2^\kappa$!).

---

Let $U$ be a set of size $2^\kappa$, and consider the set system $\mathcal{P}(U)$ (the full power set). Clearly $\mathcal{P}(U)$ has VC dimension $2^\kappa$, since it shatters $U$, but there is no subset of $U$ of size greater than $2^\kappa$ to shatter. But also the dual VC dimension is at most $\kappa$, since we would need $2^{\kappa+1}$ points in $U$ to shatter a subset of $\mathcal{P}(U)$ of size $\kappa+1$. So it remains to show that the dual VC dimension is at least $\kappa$.

This follows from the **usual bound** (see below): If the dual VC dimension of a set system is $d$, then the VC dimension of the set system is strictly less than $2^{d+1}$.

In the contrapositive, this says that if the VC dimension of a set system is at least $2^{d+1}$, then the dual VC dimension is strictly greater than $d$. Equivalently, taking $\kappa = d+1$, if the VC dimension of a set system is at least $2^{\kappa}$, then the dual VC dimension is at least $\kappa$, which is what we wanted.

---

*Proof of the usual bound:* We prove it in the modified contrapositive form, that if the VC dimension of a set system $\Phi$ on the set $U$ is at least $2^{\kappa}$, then the dual VC dimension is at least $\kappa$.

Let $A\subseteq U$ be a subset of size $2^\kappa$ which is shattered by $\Phi$. Put the elements of $A$ in bijection with binary sequences of length $\kappa$. For $a\in A$ and $n < \kappa$, write $a(n)\in \{0,1\}$ for the $n^\text{th}$ term in the corresponding sequence. Now for each $n < \kappa$, let $B_n\in \Phi$ be a set such that for all $a\in A$, $a\in B_n$ if and only if $a(n) = 1$ (we can do this since $\Phi$ shatters $A$). Then $\mathcal{B} = \{B_n\mid n<\kappa\}$ has size $\kappa$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is shattered by $A$. Indeed, for any subset $X\subseteq \mathcal{B}$, let $a\in A$ be the element such that $a(n) = 1$ if and only if $B_n\in X$. Then for all $n$, $a\in B_n$ if and only if $a(n) = 1$ if and only if $B_n\in X$. So the dual VC dimension is at least $\kappa$.

---

Incidentally, exactly the same argument shows that the **usual bound** is tight. That is, we can do better than what you asked for: We can find a set system with VC dimension $2^{\kappa+1}-1$ and dual VC dimension $\kappa$.

Let $U$ be a set of size $2^{\kappa+1}-1$, and consider the set system $\mathcal{P}(U)$. Clearly $\mathcal{P}(U)$ has VC dimension $2^{\kappa+1}-1$. But the dual VC dimension is at most $\kappa$, since we would need $2^{\kappa+1}$ elements of $U$ to shatter a subset of $\mathcal{P}(U)$ of size $\kappa+1$. And by the usual bound, since the VC dimension is at least $2^\kappa$, the dual VC dimension is at least $\kappa$, and hence equal to $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks, I was interested in the finite case, so your answer is perfect!